# Alter postgres password from python?

Tags: postgresql, python

When I run this query from psql shell everything works fine:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'somePassword';
```

but when I try exactly the same query from python (with psycopg2 package)
authentication fails when I try to connect with the password.

what can go wrong? I tried simple passwords with no non-ansi characters etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options when running code from Python,

1. Python has a method called `autocommit` you either have to turn this on,
2. or, you have to run a manual `COMMIT;` after you issue the command.

Without either of those the command will automatically `ROLLBACK;`

*answer inspired by @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments*